# How do I debug a function enqueued with rq?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-rq

I am currently attempting to debug a function that's enqueued inside a `rq` queue in VS Code.
However `rq` forks the process to produce its workers, which I think is why it is impossible to intercept the breakpoint.

I use the `debugpy` as a debugging library and I am able to break into the non-queued code and I know the function is called because it produces the proper output.

I have tried to set the worker class to `simple-worker` and set the max number of workers to 1 but that didn't work.

I have also try to explicitly call `debugpy` to listen to incoming connections inside the enqueued function. More concretely:

```
import rq

def worker_function():
    pass # Breakpoints placed here don't break
    debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678)) # Adding these lines doesn't help
    debugpy.wait_for_client()
    debugpy.breakpoint() # Doesn't break

def parent_function(rq_queue: rq.Queue):
    rq_queue.enqueue(worker_function) # Breakpoints placed here work
```

And I launch the script with the following command:

```bash
# Assume that the rq worker and redis instance are up and running
# This is the command called by the docker-compose file
python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 script.py
```

And on the VS Code side my launch configuration looks like this:

```json
{
    "configurations": [    
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "0.0.0.0",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/app"
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu You are correct, I've added a more detailed code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to start a remote debug session by using [remote-dbg](https://pypi.org/project/remote-pdb/).

First append these values to the container running `rq worker`

```yaml
environment:
  PYTHONBREAKPOINT: remote_pdb.set_trace
  REMOTE_PDB_HOST: 0.0.0.0
  REMOTE_PDB_PORT: 4444
ports:
  - "4444:4444"
```

Add this to break into the code:

```py
RemotePdb(host="0.0.0.0", port=4444).set_trace()
```

Finally access the debugger using telnet:

```bash
telnet localhost 4444
```